# select data from first table based on two forigen key in another table using linq

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, foreign-keys

I have two tables

tbl_news
tbl_NewsRelation

in tbl_NewsRelation I have two foreign key
in first foreign key I keep a news ID
and in second I keep related news ID

[tbl_news](https://www.upsara.com/images/fcz9_tblnews.jpg)

[tbl_NewsRelation](https://www.upsara.com/images/my9s_tblnewsrelation.jpg)

I need to fetch all related news for a news

for example news1 has 3 related news

news3

news4

news6

...............................

**how can do it using linq?**

In another word I need do the below:

```
var query= select * from tbl_relation where FK_NewsID=1
foreach var item in query
{
select * from tbl_news where Id=Fk_RelatedNewsID
}
```

**you can download script of tables in link below**
[script](https://uploadfiles.io/)

Comment: It would really help if you posted some sample data with your expected result.

Comment: @Error_2646 I posted two image, also expected result, as I posted my expected result is news3, news4, news 6 that are related news for news1

Comment: Can't see your images, also posting images is frowned upon - post usable, readable, copyable text.

Comment: @user3250818 https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: ok, let me add scripts of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of ways to do this with LINQ. The first uses a subquery and `Contains`, the second uses `join`.

```
var relatedNewsIDs = from n in tbl_NewsRelation
                     where n.newsID == "news1"
                     select n.relatedNewsID;

var ans = from n in tbl_news
          where relatedNewsIDs.Contains(n.newsID)
          select n;
```

Second query using `join`:

```
var ans2 = from rn in tbl_NewsRelation
           where rn.newsID == "news1"
           join n in tbl_news on rn.relatedNewsID equals n.newsID
           select n;
```